# ngrx 4 testing effects jasmine-marbles

Tags: angular, jasmine, ngrx-effects

I am working on testing effects in ngrx store. And after updating ngrx to version I've found that the way, how to test it, has been changed.

```
import { hot, cold } from 'jasmine-marbles';

it('should work', () => {
   actions = hot('--a-', { a: SomeAction });

   const expected = cold('--b', { b: AnotherAction });

   expect(effects.someSource$).toBeObservable(expected);
});
```

Unfortunately I didn't find any documentations for jasmine-marbles. 
Could anybody explain what mean the first parameter for hot an cold functions? And is it possible to find any documentation about it?

Comment: How do you use the `toBeObservable` matcher? I get "Property 'toBeObservable' does not exist on type 'Matchers'" error!

Comment: It works for me, without any errors.

Comment: @haemhweg You need to install `jasmine-marbles` to be able to use `toBeObservable`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally found some documentation about it
https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/testing#marble-diagrams

Probably it would be helpful to some one else.

Comment: above link is dead. I'm not sure, but this one seems to be its successor: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/testing/marble-testing#time-progression-syntax

Comment: Would be nice to include some of the links contents in the description. Links change and die frequently, and we will be left with empty answer.